# Should we use Promise.all in this case? Detail in content

Tags: node.js

In a function, we have to check the data is valid or not before do processing and handle logic. Something need to check the data is existed in database or not, if not existed I return 404 error immediate and stop function. But some functions need check more than 1 data need existed.

Sample:

```
function async test(_idA, _idB, _idC) {
  const a = await findOneA({ _id: _idA });
  if (!a) {
    throw Error('A does not exists');
  }

  const b = await findOneB({ _id: _idB });
  if (!b) {
    throw Error('B does not exists');
  }

  const c = await findOneC({ _id: _idC });
  if (!c) {
    throw Error('C does not exists');
  }
}
```

or

```
function async test(_idA, _idB, _idC) {
  const result = await Promise.all([
    findOneA({ _id: _idA }),
    findOneB({ _id: _idB }),
    findOneC({ _id: _idC }),
  ])
  const a = result[0];
  if (!a) {
    throw Error('A does not exists');
  }

  const b = result[1];
  if (!b) {
    throw Error('B does not exists');
  }

  const c = result[2];
  if (!c) {
    throw Error('C does not exists');
  }
}
```

I know the both 2 ways have the strength, the first no need to 3 queries if a is not existed, but if both 3 is existed, we need to wait for both. But the second, we use Promise.all so 3 queries run in parallel, so it's faster but we always have to query both 3 queries.

So which way is better?

Answer (score 1):

Ok. You can do some refactor in your code:

#### Move the exception into "find" function

When you move the exception into the find function you make sure that something will return from the function, otherwise a exception will be raised.

Your code will be like:

```js
function async findOneA(param) {
  const result = ...
  ...
  if (!result)
    throw Error('A does not exists');

  return result;   
}

function async findOneB(param) {
  const result = ...
  ...
  if (!result)
    throw Error('B does not exists');

  return result;   
}

function async findOneC(param) {
  const result = ...
  ...
  if (!result)
    throw Error('C does not exists');

  return result;   
}

function async test(_idA, _idB, _idC) {
  const a = await findOneA({ _id: _idA });
  const b = await findOneB({ _id: _idB });
  const c = await findOneC({ _id: _idC });
}
```

#### Use Promise.all

Promise all will reject if one of the promises reject. Now you can use it properly

```js
function async findOneA(param) {
  const result = ...
  ...
  if (!result)
    throw Error('A does not exists');

  return result;   
}

function async findOneB(param) {
  const result = ...
  ...
  if (!result)
    throw Error('B does not exists');

  return result;   
}

function async findOneC(param) {
  const result = ...
  ...
  if (!result)
    throw Error('C does not exists');

  return result;   
}

function async test(_idA, _idB, _idC) {
  const result = await Promise.all([
    findOneA({ _id: _idA }),
    findOneB({ _id: _idB }),
    findOneC({ _id: _idC })
  ])
  const a = result[0];
  const b = result[1];
  const c = result[2];
}
```

#### Refactor you code to look cleaner

Now you can just refactor you code to look a little bit cleaner. Less verbose

```js
function async findOneA(param) {
  const result = ...
  ...
  if (!result)
    throw Error('A does not exists');

  return result;   
}

function async findOneB(param) {
  const result = ...
  ...
  if (!result)
    throw Error('B does not exists');

  return result;   
}

function async findOneC(param) {
  const result = ...
  ...
  if (!result)
    throw Error('C does not exists');

  return result;   
}

function async test(_idA, _idB, _idC) {
  const [a, b, c] = await Promise.all([
    findOneA({ _id: _idA }),
    findOneB({ _id: _idB }),
    findOneC({ _id: _idC })
  ]);
}
```

Comment: I think use are going wrong way. I just ask about we should use promise.all or single query for this case.

Comment: You could use promise all, but in order to make sure that the promise.all will stop if one of the ```find``` function got rejected, you should move the ```throw``` into the function

Comment: Usually parallel calls is better than serial calls. But it may vary depending on several factors. How many parallel calls are you making? Are they multithread or single thread? Is there a concurrency for some resource? In this particular case I think Promise.all is better than serial call.

Comment: Do you think how many calls then we should use promise.all ?

Comment: I would run a performance test to make a good choice of promises running in a promise.all in a particular program.